# How can I get the mov play time second

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

why get a second num is 0.00000 with bottom process

```
 NSURL    *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"s26a.mov"];

NSDictionary *opts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
                                                                   forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey];                    
 AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:movieURL options:opts]; 
 float minute = 0;
 float second = 0; 
 second = urlAsset.duration.value / urlAsset.duration.timescale; 
 NSLog(@"movie duration : %f", second);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get movie duration like this:

```
 Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([urlAsset duration]); // any AVURLAsset
```

Comment: Do you means like this way? NSURL    *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"s26a.mov"];

NSDictionary *opts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
                                                                   forKey:AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey];                    
 AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:movieURL options:opts];  Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([urlAsset duration] // any AVURLAsset

Comment: yes like this. perfect unless your urlAsset reference created